# Error: starting an activity from list's onItemClick with CursorAdapter

Tags: android, android-listview, android-contacts, android-cursoradapter

I'm trying to build a contact application

In the main activity i Show a list of all the contacts.

However, when I try to launch an activity after an item from
the list has been clicked, I get Error:

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main 01-20 09:54:48.407: E/AndroidRuntime(8459):
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: this should only be called when the
>   cursor is valid

It seems that somehow the adapter methods (getView, getCount) keep calling

My Code is as follows,

```
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle)
{
    super.onCreate(icicle);

    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    initComponents();

    final String sortOrder = ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + " COLLATE LOCALIZED ASC";

    c = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, sortOrder);

    startManagingCursor(c);

    final MySimpleArrayAdapter adapter = new MySimpleArrayAdapter(mContext, c);

    list.setAdapter(adapter);

    list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
        {
             Intent intent  = new Intent (mContext, SingleContact.class);
                         startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

}

/**
 * An adapter which handle the contacts
 * 
 * @author intel
 * 
 */
public class MySimpleArrayAdapter extends CursorAdapter
{
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    private Cursor cur;

    public MySimpleArrayAdapter(Context context, Cursor c)
    {
        super(context, c);
        this.mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.cur = c;
    }

    public MySimpleArrayAdapter(Context context, Cursor c, boolean a)
    {
        super(context, c, a);
        this.mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.cur = c;
    }

    @Override
    public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor)
    {
        TextView tvName = null;

        tvName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.contact_item_text_view_name);

        tvName.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME)));
    }

    @Override
    public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        TextView tvName = null;

        ImageView ivPhoto;

        mInflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        View convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.contact_item, parent, false);

        tvName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.contact_item_text_view_name);

        tvName.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME)));

        return convertView;
    }


    @Override
    public int getCount()
    {
        Thread.dumpStack();

        return cur.getCount();
    }

}
```

Here's the log:

> 01-20 09:54:48.407: E/AndroidRuntime(8459): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   01-20 09:54:48.407: E/AndroidRuntime(8459): java.lang.IllegalStateException: this should only be called when the cursor is valid
>   01-20 09:54:48.407: E/AndroidRuntime(8459):     at android.widget.CursorAdapter.getView(CursorAdapter.java:175)
>   01-20 09:54:48.407: E/AndroidRuntime(8459):     at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:1409)
>   01-20 09:54:48.407: E/AndroidRuntime(8459):     at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1307)
>   01-20 09:54:48.407: E/AndroidRuntime(8459):     at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1127)
>   01-20 09:54:48.407: E/AndroidRuntime(8459):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8510)
>   01-20 09:54:48.407: E/AndroidRuntime(8459):     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChild(RelativeLayout.java:566)
>   01-20 09:54:48.407: E/AndroidRuntime(8459):     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:381)
>   01-20 09:54:48.407: E/AndroidRuntime(8459):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8510)
>   01-20 09:54:48.407: E/AndroidRuntime(8459):     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:581)
>   01-20 09:54:48.407: E/AndroidRuntime(8459):     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:365)
>   01-20 09:54:48.407: E/AndroidRuntime(8459):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8510)
>   01-20 09:54:48.407: E/AndroidRuntime(8459):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3202)
>   01-20 09:54:48.407: E/AndroidRuntime(8459):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:250)
>   01-20 09:54:48.407: E/AndroidRuntime(8459):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8510)
>   01-20 09:54:48.407: E/AndroidRuntime(8459):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3202)
>   01-20 09:54:48.407: E/AndroidRuntime(8459):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:250)
>   01-20 09:54:48.407: E/AndroidRuntime(8459):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8510)
>   01-20 09:54:48.407: E/AndroidRuntime(8459):     at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:871)
>   01-20 09:54:48.407: E/AndroidRuntime(8459):     at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1921)
>   01-20 09:54:48.407: E/AndroidRuntime(8459):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>   01-20 09:54:48.407: E/AndroidRuntime(8459):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:143)
>   01-20 09:54:48.407: E/AndroidRuntime(8459):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4196)
>   01-20 09:54:48.407: E/AndroidRuntime(8459):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>   01-20 09:54:48.407: E/AndroidRuntime(8459):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
>   01-20 09:54:48.407: E/AndroidRuntime(8459):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
>   01-20 09:54:48.407: E/AndroidRuntime(8459):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
>   01-20 09:54:48.407: E/AndroidRuntime(8459):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Please help me regarding this.

Comment: Properly analyze your logs before posting it on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

But how can you say that error is coming from your pasted code...
as your class "MySimpleArrayAdapter" is not involved in error logs.
I do not think error is coming from your pasted code...